# Native query causing null pointer exception

Tags: java, sql, nullpointerexception

At this point I am very confused. I have a controller that uses my DAO to run a query, but it is giving me a null pointer exception. I have been solving error after error but can't seem to get to the root of them all.

Controller:

```
DAO d = new DAO();
List<objects> foo = d.callQuery(new object());
```

DAO:

```
        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    cal.set(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 0, 0, 0);

    Date begin = new Date(cal.getTimeInMillis());
    Date end = new Date(cal.getTimeInMillis());

    String theQuery = "SELECT * from table1";
    Query query = em.createNativeQuery(theQuery).setParameter("begin", begin).setParameter("end", end);
```

Error leads me to this line: `Query query = em.createNativeQuery(theQuery).setParameter("begin", begin).setParameter("end", end);`

What could possibly be null? Note: this is not my full query, my full query is working and contains both parameters.

I printed `begin` and `end` and they both gave me the expected results. The stack trace leads me from the second line of my controller to the create query line.

Comment: What does the stacktrace say?

Comment: The stack trace leads me from the second line of my controller to the create query line. @Reimeus

Comment: what parameters you trying insert? your query haven't any parameters

Comment: @AlekseiBulgak please read my note:"Note: this is not my full query, my full query is working and contains both parameters."

Comment: Is it possible to split up that long string of method calls into discrete calls? That might aid with debugging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like I need more information, but trying to give you some clue:

- How do you get the em object? Maybe em is null...
- The query that you are using, is "SELECT * from table1"? I ask it because you are setting parameters to a query that doesn´t have parameters.

I hope these questions can help.

Comment: I did not want to share my full query, but I know for a fact that it works because it has worked and remains unchanged. I will try to debug for `em`, that may be the problem. Indeed, my entity manager is null.